# SQL Server: geography polygon is inverse of WKT (srid 4326)

Tags: sql-server, geometry, sql-server-2016

When I have a basic shape, both the geometry and geography form the same shape:

```
DECLARE @shapegeo geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326);  
DECLARE @shapegeom geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326);  


SELECT @shapegeo;
SELECT @shapegeom;
```

[image]

When I have a more complex shape that was generated from polygon tool from: https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html

The geometry is the correct shape, but the geography is FULLGLOBE - shape:

```
DECLARE @ovalgeo geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-83.221435546875 40.119237128467624,-83.1280517578125 40.253525039452626,-82.9302978515625 40.29543548046365,-82.7490234375 40.257717252394976,-82.6776123046875 40.19900263907047,-82.5897216796875 40.08982621705029,-82.5732421875 39.9383693235635,-82.63916015625 39.828774835536194,-82.935791015625 39.74435221539322,-83.21044921875 39.80767889257094,-83.287353515625 39.87516311271822,-83.3148193359375 39.98468347687377,-83.221435546875 40.119237128467624))', 4326).MakeValid();  
DECLARE @ovalgeom geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-83.221435546875 40.119237128467624,-83.1280517578125 40.253525039452626,-82.9302978515625 40.29543548046365,-82.7490234375 40.257717252394976,-82.6776123046875 40.19900263907047,-82.5897216796875 40.08982621705029,-82.5732421875 39.9383693235635,-82.63916015625 39.828774835536194,-82.935791015625 39.74435221539322,-83.21044921875 39.80767889257094,-83.287353515625 39.87516311271822,-83.3148193359375 39.98468347687377,-83.221435546875 40.119237128467624))', 4326).MakeValid();  


SELECT @ovalgeo;
SELECT @ovalgeom;
```

[image]

```
DECLARE @squaregeo geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-121.025390625 48.73717255965176,-94.04296875 48.73717255965176,-94.04296875 28.9060038852843,-121.025390625 28.9060038852843,-121.025390625 48.73717255965176))', 4326).MakeValid();  
DECLARE @squaregeom geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-121.025390625 48.73717255965176,-94.04296875 48.73717255965176,-94.04296875 28.9060038852843,-121.025390625 28.9060038852843,-121.025390625 48.73717255965176))', 4326).MakeValid();  


SELECT @squaregeo;
SELECT @squaregeom;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a ring orientation problem. With geography polygons, the order in which you specify the points matters. That is, given points A, B, C, and D, `POLYGON(A, B, C, D, A)` is not the same as `POLYGON(A, D, C, B, A)`. They are related in that the union of both of them is going to be the whole globe. Said another way, if one of those two polygons is, say, Central Park, the other will be the entire globe with a Central Park-shaped hole in it.

So what can you do about it? If you find that you have a "most of the globe" sized shape, you can call the `ReorientObject()` method on it. A heuristic that I use to determine whether I need to do that is by calling `EnvelopeAngle()` on the object. If that's too big (my threshold is 90 degrees), I reorient the object and that's probably correct.